# Reverting a custom view

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I am working on an app that utilizes a custom view,MainView.java which extends View, by setting the view from the MainActivity on an onClick using:

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if(view.getId() == R.id.button){
               MainView = new MainView(this);
               setContentView(MainView);
               MainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
           }
        }
```

The MainView runs the game and if the player "loses" I want the screen to return to showing the initial activity_main.xml, or any other suitable View. I detect the loss in MainView's update() method.

```
    private void update() {
    if(lives == 0){
        reset();
    }
    if(score >= lvlScore){
        levelUp();
    }
    for(Projectile proj: balls) {//set positions good balls
        proj.setPosition();
    }
    for(Projectile proj: badBalls){//set positions bad balls
        proj.setPosition();
    }
```

What I have been unable to even figure out what to do is retrieve information from MainView in my Activity, like the score, and how to revert my custom view back to the initial XML based on something that happens in MainView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an interface to communicate back to the Activity, just as you would for a click listener. For example, in your `MainView` class:

```
// Keep a reference to a listener that should be notified of events
private GameEventListener mListener;

// An interface defining events that a listener will receive
public interface GameEventListener {
    void onWin();
    void onLoss();
}

public void setGameEventListener(GameEventListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

private void notifyGameWon() {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onWin();
    }
}

private void notifyGameLost() {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onLoss();
    }
}
```

Then, in your Activity:

```
// Have your Activity implement the GameEventListener interface
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements GameEventListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (R.id.button = view.getId()) {
            MainView mainView = new MainView(this);
            mainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            // Since your Activity implements this interface, you can just
            // set `this` as the listener. Whenever your MainView class
            // calls one of the notify() methods, the implementations below
            // will be triggered.
            mainView.setGameListener(this);
            setContentView(mainView);
        }
    }

    @Override public void onWin() {
        // Reset your view here
    }

    @Override public void onLoss() {
        // Reset your view here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give your MainView a reference to your activity.

in main view...

```
public void setParentActivity(final Activity activity){
  this.mActivity = activity;
}
```

altered on click

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
       if(view.getId() == R.id.button){
           MainView = new MainView(this);
           setContentView(MainView);
           MainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
           MainView.setParentActivity(this);
       }
    }
```

Comment: That adds tight coupling between a View and the hosting Activity.

Comment: Yeah an interface like you suggested is better for sure. A little more advanced than I thought Worley was looking for since he couldn't figure it out on his own...